# Volley Library doesn't work on android 4.4 kitkat, why?

Tags: java, android, android-volley, android-4.4-kitkat

I wrote a small code using volley library 1.1.0 and 1.0.0 version, it works fine on all android versions, but recently my code doesn't work on android 4.4, and there's no error, it just reach the (onErrorResponse) when i make an HTTP request.
Any suggestions

Answer (score 1):

Are you using TLS1.1 or TLS 1.2. Android 4.4 and below do not support these and that might be the reason.

Comment: Yes, Thank you for letting me know